# Python: what is the difference between a package and a compiler?

Tags: python, numba

I was reading the wiki page for Numba, and it says Numba is a "compiler". But then later on, it says that to use Numba, you import it like a package. I later looked up how to use Numba, and indeed, you just pip install it.

So now I am confused. I thought Numba was a compiler? But it seems to be used just like any other package, like numpy or pandas? What's the difference?

[image: Numba is known as a "compiler" but you import it like a module]

Comment: There is no "difference" between a package and a compiler. A package is how you *get* Numba and a compiler is what it *does*.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler is a program that inputs something in human-readable form (usually a program in a specified language) and outputs a functionally equivalent stream in another, more machine-digestible form.  Just as with any other transformation, it's equally viable as a command-line invocation or a function call.

As long as it's wrapped properly in a package for general use, it's perfect reasonable to deliver a compiler as a Python package.

Does that clear up the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read at Numba documentation it's a package that you import to you project and then use the Numba decorator do indicate parts of your code that you would like to have compiled in JIT (Just in Time) in order to optimize them. Like in the following example:

```
from numba import jit
import random

@jit(nopython=True)
def monte_carlo_pi(nsamples):
    acc = 0
    for i in range(nsamples):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        if (x ** 2 + y ** 2) < 1.0:
            acc += 1
    return 4.0 * acc / nsamples
```

When the `monte_carlo_pi` function is called Numba will have it compiled in order to optimize it, so there isn't a compilation step that you can take.